# using NOT IN clause in criteria query

Tags: sql, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

it may seem like duplicate question but my problem is not solving. i have following tables:-

```
------------------------------------------------------
  student                        student_fine
   st_id                           fine_id
   st_name                         fine_description
   st_class                        fine_amount
                                   st_id
 -------------------------------------------------------

 query required: "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT.ST_ID NOT IN 
                  (SELECT STUDENT_FINE.ST_ID FROM STUDENT)"

 criteria query code i used:
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class); 
 DetachedCriteria detachedcriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(StudentFine.class); 
 detachedcriteria.setProjection(Property.forName("st_id")); 
 criteria.add(Property.forName("st_id").notIn(detachedcriteria)); 
  ...
```

i am getting a list with no records while sql command line returns 2 records. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You got confused by your own caps: `(SELECT STUDENT_FINE.ST_ID FROM STUDENT)` -->> `(SELECT ST_ID FROM STUDENT_FINE)

Comment: thanks for correction.

Comment: Please don't correct the error in the question. [ I rolled it back to the 1st version]

Comment: If you correct the error in the question, nobody else will be able to figure out what the error was.  That's why not to correct it.  :)